# Excel Formula calculates in one cell but not another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a formula in Excel that's returning #N/A in one cell. However, if I go to another cell and enter the same formula it is calculating properly. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Please let us know what your formula is, what you expect, and perhaps some sample data.

Comment: =IF(IF($B$3>='http://sharepointsite/[APU-5.xlsm]Jan - Jun Helicopter'!$B$1,(HLOOKUP((TODAY()),('http://sharepointsite/[APU-5.xlsm]Jul - Dec Helicopter'!$B$1:$GA$57),5,FALSE)),(HLOOKUP((TODAY()),('http://sharepointsite/[APU-5.xlsm]Jan - Jun Helicopter'!$B$1:$GA$57),5,FALSE)))=0,"NO RPT",(IF($B$3>='http://sharepointsite/Active_Schedules/[APU-5.xlsm]Jul - Dec Helicopter'!$B$1,(HLOOKUP((TODAY()),('http://sharepointsite/[APU-5.xlsm]Jul - Dec Helicopter'!$B$1:$GA$57),5,FALSE)),(HLOOKUP((TODAY()),('http://sharepointsite/[APU-5.xlsm]Jan - Jun Helicopter'!$B$1:$GA$57),5,FALSE)))))

Comment: Once it figures out if it's the Jan - Jun or Jul - Dec Sheet it looks for row 5, which is a dropdown selection and places that in the spreadsheet (i.e. up, down or m/x)

Answer (score 1):

Did you fixate all the cells which should stay? You can do so by adding "$" in front of the row and/or the column $A$1 always stays on A1 when dragging/copying to another cell. A$1 always stays on the first column, $A1 always stays on the first row. Maybe one of your cells refers to an empty cell?

Comment: The formula works if I move to another cell and paste it.